# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bannable')

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
    message.mentions.members.forEach(men => {
      let member = message.mentions.members.get(men)

      if (!member.bannable) return message.reply(not_bannable)
    
      const reason = args.slice(1).join(" ");
      member.ban({reason: reason || "no reason"}).then((member) => {
        message.channel.send(member + " banned by " + message.author.id)
      }).catch(err => console.log(err))
  })
```

I'm trying to build a ban command that allows you to ban multiple users at once. Unfortunately, an error occurs when I execute it.

I work with discord v13

Why does this error occur?

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bannable')
```

Comment: `men` is the `Member` object, not an id --- just replace `men` with `member` and remove the `let member = ...`

Comment: This error message means `member` is not defined, which leads to `undefined.bannable`. There must be a problem with `message.mentions.members.get(men)`.

Comment: Maybe you can use `men` directly, since `message.mentions.members.forEach` iterates over an `array` of members, I guess...

Answer (score 0):

Use `men` since it's already a `GuildMember` object

```js
message.mentions.members.forEach(men => {

      if (!men.bannable) return message.reply(not_bannable)
    
      const reason = args.slice(1).join(" ");
      men.ban({reason: reason || "no reason"}).then((member) => {
        message.channel.send(member + " banned by " + message.author.id)
      }).catch(err => console.log(err))
  })
```